# my sql says words must be unique

Tags: sql, unique

i have been learning sql and upon making my table to learn this better i made one about pokemon. but my problem is it's saying words must be unique. i haven't learned that or seen it being done on khan academy yet and not getting an answer isn't helping the learning curve.

```
 name TEXT,
    height NUMERIC,
    weight NUMERIC,
    hp INTEGER,
    attack INTEGER,
    special attack INTEGER,
    defense INTEGER,
    special defense INTEGER,
    speed INTEGER,
    special ability INTEGER,
    hidden ability INTEGER
    );
```

and the error is showing "You have multiple columns named `special` - column names must be unique."

Comment: This is because the column names, with spaces, must be **quoted** so that MySQL can correctly parse the command. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html for how to correctly deal with column names with spaces (or other odd characters, or that collide with keywords). While there is good reason to avoid spaces (and other "quirky characters") and stick with simpler names, spaces are valid in SQL/MySQL identifiers.

Comment: what is your RDBMS? oracle, mysql, sqlserver, postgre?

Answer (score 1):

Use qoute, caret or braces if you want to define a column with a space in between like below. But generally having a space in column names is possible but NOT recommended due to extra effort.

```
ORACLE:
  "special defense" INTEGER

MYSQL:
 `special defense` INTEGER

SQLSERVER:
  [special defense] INTEGER
```

Answer (score 0):

Column names shouldn't contain spaces.  Replace the spaces in your column names with underscores.  For example, `special_defense`.

Comment: Shouldn't is subjective and column names with spaces are valid identifiers *if* correctly quoted: "Permitted characters in quoted identifiers *include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)*, except U+0000:". Make sure to start with technical details, then add useful/practical suggestions.

Comment: ok tyvm. but now it's saying this > table pokemon has 12 columns but 14 values were supplied. if anyone needs the full code i'll gladly post it if it'll help out. i'm sorry i'm still learning this stuff.